# Disable ESLint for TypeScript files

Tags: typescript, webstorm, eslint, lint, tslint

I have a big web app made by both legacy JavaScript code (including eslint) and new TypeScript code (including tslint).

My problem is that my IDE (WebStorm) is automatically applying both linters to all files, so in TypeScript I get errors from eslint that I should not get.

How can I make sure eslint is applied only to *.js files and not to the *.ts files (that instead should only be checked by tslint) ?

Answer (score 6):

You can try adding `*.ts` to an `.eslintignore`.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/eslint.html#ws_eslint_suppress_linting_typescript

Answer (score 5):

Webstorm is only following the config define by you (If you have both plugins activated on the project), you have to add to your `.eslintignore` the following:

```
**/*.ts
```

And in your `tslint.json` something like:

```js
{
  "extends": "tslint:latest",
  "linterOptions": {
      "exclude": [
          "bin",
          "**/*.js"
      ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Vscode, follow these steps:

1. Go to setting `CMD+,` or `CRTL+,` on mac and windows respectively.
2. Search for `eslint:probe`
3. Remove typescript